# How can I find the big endian key in a message?

Tags: python, binary, mqtt, endianness

I am trying to read a binary message from an ESP32 using a broker; i wrote a phyton script where I subscribe the topic. the message that i actually receive is:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00?'
```

this is a float binary little endian message but I don't the key to decode it. Is there a way to find the decode key based on this data?
This is my python code:

```
    import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt


def on_connect1(client1,  userdata1, flags1, rc1):
    
    client1.subscribe("ESP32DevKit123/mytopic")

def on_message1(client1, userdata1, msg1):
    print(msg1.topic+" "+ "TESTENZA: "+str(msg1.payload))

client1 = mqtt.Client()

client1.username_pw_set(username="myuser",password="mypassword")

client1.on_connect = on_connect1

client1.on_message = on_message1

client1.connect("linkclient", portnumber, 60)


def twosComplement_hex(hexval):
    bits = 16 # Number of bits in a hexadecimal number format
    on_message1 = int(hexval, bits)
    if on_message1 & (1 << (bits-1)):
    on_message1 -= 1 << bits
    return on_message1


client1.loop_forever()
```

It also gives me an error in the line  on_message1 -= 1 << bits; the error says: Expected intended block pylance. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you provided is `b'\x00\x00\x00?'` - I'm going to assume that this is  `0000003f` (please output hex with `msg1.payload.hex()`).

I'll also assume that by "float binary little endian" you mean a big endian floating point (IEE754) - note that this does not match up with the algorithm you are using ([twos compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)). Plugging this input into an [online tool](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/) indicates that the expected result ("Float - Big Endian (ABCD)") is `8.82818e-44` (it's worth checking with this tool; sometimes the encoding may not be what you think it is!).

Lets unpack this using python (see the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) docs for more information):

```
>>> from struct import unpack
>>> unpack('>f', b'\x00\x00\x00\x3f')[0]
8.828180325246348e-44
```

Notes:

- The `[0]` is there because `unpack` returns an array (you can unpack more than one item from the input)
- `>f` - the `>` means big-endian and the `f` float (standard size = 4 bytes)

The reason your original code gives the error "Expected intended block" is due to the lack of indentation in the line `on_message1 -= 1 << bits` (as it follows an `if` it needs to be indented). The algorithm does not appear relevant to your task (but there may be details I'm missing).